# Admob Advanced Native ads Cause crash on click of item in A RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads

Below is my code snippets.

1) CustomAdapter

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    // A menu item view type.
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

    // The unified native ad view type.
    private static final int UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    ListActivity listActivity;
    List<Object> mModelList;

    public CustomAdapter(ListActivity listActivity, List<Object> modelList) {
        this.listActivity = listActivity;
        this.mModelList = modelList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        switch (viewType) {
            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                View unifiedNativeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                        parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_unified,
                        parent, false);
                return new UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                // Fall through.
            default:
                //inflate layout
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.model_layout, parent, false);
        MenuItemViewHolder holder = new MenuItemViewHolder(itemView);
        //Handle item clicks here
        holder.setOnClickListener(new MenuItemViewHolder.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Model modelList = (Model) mModelList.get(position);
                //This is called when user clicks item

                String id = modelList.getId();
                String title = modelList.getTitle();
                String description = modelList.getDescription();
                Long time = modelList.getTime();

                //intent to start activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity, PostDetails.class);
                //put data in intent
                intent.putExtra("pId", id);
                intent.putExtra("pTitle", title);
                intent.putExtra("pDescription", description);
                intent.putExtra("pTime", time);
                //start activity
                listActivity.startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        });
        return holder;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType){

            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mModelList.get(position);
                populateNativeAdView(nativeAd, ((UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
                break;
            default:
                // fall through
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:

                MenuItemViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;
                Model modelList = (Model) mModelList.get(position);

        //bind views / set data
                menuItemHolder.mTitleTv.setText(modelList.getTitle());
                menuItemHolder.mDescriptionTv.setText(modelList.getDescription());
                menuItemHolder.setTime(modelList.getTime());

    }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mModelList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Object recyclerViewItem = mModelList.get(position);
        if (recyclerViewItem instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
            return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
        return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    private void populateNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd,
                                      UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {
        // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());

        // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
        // check before trying to display them.
        NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();

        if (icon == null) {
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                    .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Assign native ad object to the native view.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
    }
}
```

2) MenuItemViewHolder class

```java
public class MenuItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitleTv, mDescriptionTv, mPostTimeTv;
    View mView;

    public MenuItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        //item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });

        //iten long Click Listener
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemLongClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }
        });
        //set time


        //initialize views with model_layout.xml
        mTitleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
        mDescriptionTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
        mPostTimeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTime);


    }
    public void setTime(Long time) {
        TextView txtTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.postTime);
        //long elapsedDays=0,elapsedWeeks = 0, elapsedHours=0,elapsedMin=0;
        long elapsedTime;
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int elapsed = (int) ((currentTime - time) / 1000);
        if (elapsed < 60) {
            if (elapsed < 2) {
                txtTime.setText("Just Now");
            } else {
                txtTime.setText(elapsed + " sec ago");
            }
        } else if (elapsed > 604799) {
            elapsedTime = elapsed / 604800;
            if (elapsedTime == 1) {
                txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " week ago");
            } else {

                txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " weeks ago");
            }
        } else if (elapsed > 86399) {
            elapsedTime = elapsed / 86400;
            if (elapsedTime == 1) {
                txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " day ago");
            } else {
                txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " days ago");
            }
        } else if (elapsed > 3599) {
            elapsedTime = elapsed / 3600;
            if (elapsedTime == 1) {
                txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " hour ago");
            } else {
                txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " hours ago");
            }
        } else if (elapsed > 59) {
            elapsedTime = elapsed / 60;
            txtTime.setText(elapsedTime + " min ago");


        }

    }
    private MenuItemViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;


    //Interface for click listener
    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener (MenuItemViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {
        mClickListener = clickListener;

    }


}
```

3) ListActivity

```java
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Object> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    //private AdView adView;
    // The number of native ads to load and display.
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 5;

    // The AdLoader used to load ads.
    private AdLoader adLoader;

    // List of native ads that have been successfully loaded.
    private List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();


    //layout manager for recyclerview
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FloatingActionButton mAddBtn;

    //firestore instance
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    CustomAdapter adapter;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, String.valueOf(R.string.admob_app_id));

        //actionbar and its title
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("List Data");

        //init firestore
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //initialize views
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAddBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);




        //set Recycler views properties
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //init progree dialog
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //show data in recyclerView
        showData();
        loadNativeAds();




        //Handle Floating action button to open main activity
        mAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
    private void loadNativeAds() {

        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.native_advanced_ad));
        adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
                new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                        // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                        mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();

                        }
                    }
                }).withAdListener(
                new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                        // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                                + " load another.");
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                            //showData();
                        }
                    }
                }).build();

        // Load the Native Express ad.
        adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
    }
    private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
        if (mNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        int offset = (modelList.size() / mNativeAds.size()) + 1;
        int index = 3;
        for (UnifiedNativeAd ad: mNativeAds) {
            modelList.add(index, ad);
            index = index + offset;
        }
    }


    private void showData() {
        //set tittle of progress dialog
        pd.setTitle("Loading Data.......");

        //show progress dialog
        pd.show();

        db.collection("Documents")
                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        modelList.clear();
                        //called when data is retrieved
                        pd.dismiss();
                        //Show Data
                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                            Model model = new Model(doc.getString("id"),
                                    doc.getString("title"),
                                    doc.getString("description"),
                                    doc.getLong("time")

                            );
                            modelList.add(model);
                            //insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                        //adapter
                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListActivity.this, modelList);

                        //set adapter to recyclerview
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        //mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //called when there is any error while retrieving
                        pd.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }

}
```

My First issue is that the native ads wont load until I scroll the list
[The list loads but ads wont load until I manually scroll through and when I click on items before scrolling my app crashes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziZ6z.png)

The native ad is supposed to appear after every three items so when I click on any item below the three items the app crashes with the logcat below.

> 2019-09-24 14:24:54.373 27287-27287/com.pesadevs.firebasefirestore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.pesadevs.firebasefirestore, PID: 27287
>           java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzadl cannot be cast to com.pesadevs.firebasefirestore.Model
>               at com.pesadevs.firebasefirestore.CustomAdapter$1.onItemClick(CustomAdapter.java:59)
>               at com.pesadevs.firebasefirestore.MenuItemViewHolder$1.onClick(MenuItemViewHolder.java:21)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
>               at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
>               at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:782)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25945)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

NB: If I scroll and ads load everything works perfectly as seen in my image below.
[When ads load the app works as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTm7s.png)

I dont know what am doing wrong, any help would be appriciated thanks.

Comment: any solutions found? have the same problem

Comment: I think the fact that you are modifying the data set after the recycler is shown is causing the problem. If you are calling `showData()` first and then `loadNativeAds()`, the data set of the recycler view has changed. This requires you to call an explicit. `notifyDatasetChanged()` method of your Recycler adapter.